# Google Analytics for Wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics

I have the Google Analytics for wordpress plugin produce by http://yoast.com

I have it installed on two blogs. On one it works perfectly... the other it does not work.

Both designs are custom designed. As such the only thing i can think is that the designs are coded in different ways such that the plugin inst inserting the code into one of my sites.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: how is anybody supposed to help you when you didn't explain what you mean by "not working" and didn't provide any code or link(s) to the stuff that's "not working"?

Comment: The blog in question is anfield.com
The analytics code is not included...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the page source of each site to see if GA is loading. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) as well, to see what's loading in terms of the javascripts involved with GA.

Is `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php of your theme? That's required for plugins to load. See [Function Reference/wp head « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head)

Comment: It is not. I know this... I am trying to work out why it is not being included. cHEERS

Comment: Is <?php wp_head(); ?> in your header.php?

Comment: Thankyou. As an aside what is this wp_head function? It fixed the problem but without it everything else worked fine..

Comment: Plugins need wp_head to hook into the page and load their functions. See the documentation link above. Some themes don't include it, but that's unusual.